# XCode 8 - Change constraints according to orientation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

Here is my problem.

I have a square image which does not fit on an iPad or iPhone app, as the screens are not square, so i decided to add a UIImageView which:

When the Phone is on Portrait position i add a constraint to the top (-20) and bottom (0) to fill the whole screen aligning X in the center and keeping the aspect ratio to keep the image square even if the screen is bigger or smaller, this means that in both sides i will "loose" part of my image, but that is fine.

When I rotate my phone to landscape position, the screen is widder,so i see a square image in the middle of the screen but a white rectangle in both sides.
I think the sollution to this is when it is on landscape position i need to remove the top and bottom constraints and add one to lead (-20) and one to trail (-20), center the image on Y axis and keep the 1:1 ratio...

**But my question is: how to add a constraint to valid for one orientarion and change it to the other?**

**What is the best approach?**

thanks

FP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do it programmatically. I recommend you make the view fill the superview -- have one constraint each to top, bottom, left, and right. Then for the UIImageView attributes inspector in Interface Builder, set "View Mode" to Aspect Fill.

Comment: I will test this, but I have my doubts if the image will be centralized.. I don't mind to lose part of the image but it need to be a small part on each side

Comment: Yusuf, that is exactly what i was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it the wrong way around.

While on portrait you should set trail and lead constraints as your height is bigger than the width, so if you set (0) for trail and lead and 1:1 ratio you are safe that it will fit beautifully. Also center it vertically in container.

On landscape, as the width is bigger than the height, you should set top and bottom (0) and ratio 1:1 and center it horizontally in container.

Comment: No what I wrote is correct, otherwise I will have white space on the top and on the bottom on portrait and on the left and on the right in the landscape

Comment: Hmm, so the challenge is to square the rectangle?! You have two choices, you can either go with what i suggested, you will have "white space" but your whole image will fit or you can go with Yusuf's suggestion and you will have no white space but you will lose quite a bit of your image.. I guess it all comes down to the image that is displayed.. The white space that you mention is the background, why dont you set it to a color that compliments your image so it doesnt look off..

Comment: Actually what Yusuf suggested is exactly what i was looking for... thanks for your help, i appreciate it